# Regex String Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need, The Regex String for only Accept a-zA-Z9-0 And / -

Sorry for the inconvenience, Many Thanks.

Comment: In the future, please show some effort on your part for solving your issue. This question makes it appear as if you didn't try _anything_, which also makes it disruptive to our community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simething like this should work:

```
/^[-\/a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

Comment: thanks, In a moment, accepts this answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[a-zA-Z9-0\/-]+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

the pattern: ^[a-zA-Z0-9/-]+$ should do it.

Example:

```
var myregexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\/-]+$/img;
var match = myregexp.exec(yourString);
```